# Matrix representation of a measurement

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement

It is well known that any operation on a quantum computer is described with a unitary matrix (a quantum gate) because quantum computing is reversible.

Only non-reversible operation is a measurement of a qubit. Therefore, I would expect that the measurement can be described by a non-unitary matrix (or even by matrix that is not invertible).

A result of the measurement should be a probability distribution of all possible states of measured qubits.

**My question:** How does a matrix representing measurement of qubit(s) look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no single matrix representing measurement. Projective measurements are represented by a set of orthogonal projectors. For example, measurement of a single qubit in the standard basis is represented by projectors
$$\pi_0=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\pi_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0\\
0 &1
\end{pmatrix}$$

If a qubit was initially in state with density matrix $\rho$, then the post-measurement density matrix $\rho'$ is

$$\rho'=\sum_{i=0}^1\pi_i\rho\pi_i$$

Also, probability distribution of possible measurement outcomes can be obtained only by multiple measurements on an ensemble of identical systems; a single measurement gives no information about probabilities of possible measurement outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

These are called observables, which are unitary hermitian matrices whose eigenvectors are the possible outcomes of the measurement. For example, the observable of the standard computational basis is the Pauli Z operator, and the observable of the sign basis is the Pauli X operator.